# How to search in a BYTE array for a pattern?

Tags: c++, c

I have a Byte array :

`BYTE Buffer[20000];`  this array contains the following data:

> 00FFFFFFFFFFFF0010AC4C4053433442341401030A2F1E78EEEE95A3544C99260F5054A54B00714F8180B3000101010101010101010121399030621A274068B03600DA281100001C000000FF003457314D44304353423443530A000000FC0044454C4C2050323231300A2020000000FD00384B1E5310000A20202020202000FA

My question is how can I search this array for a pattern like "`000000FC`"? I don't really think it is important, but I need the index where I can find my pattern too.

Comment: It's exactly the same as searching for a substring in a larger string. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) has plenty of information.

Comment: Looks like [strstr()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html) (in C, don't know about C++) does what you want.

Comment: @pmg: `strstr()` works on zero-terminated arrays. It won't work on these, which contain zero-valued bytes.

Comment: +1 @Mike: I assumed the data exists as shown. If the "00" means "\x00" then `strstr()` is not right.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since you're in C++, do it the C++ way:

```
char a[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0xFC };
char Buffer[20000] = ...

std::string needle(a, a + 4);
std::string haystack(Buffer, Buffer + 20000);  // or "+ sizeof Buffer"

std::size_t n = haystack.find(needle);

if (n == std::string::npos)
{
    // not found
}
else
{
    // position is n
}
```

You can also use an algorithm to search the array directly:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

auto it = std::search(
    std::begin(Buffer), std::end(Buffer),
    std::begin(a), std::end(a));

if (it == std::end(Buffer))
{
    // not found
}
else
{
    // subrange found at std::distance(std::begin(Buffer), it)
}
```

Or, in C++17, you can use a string view:

```
std::string_view sv(std::begin(Buffer), std::end(Buffer));

if (std::size_t n = sv.find(needle); n != sv.npos)
{
    // found at position n
}
else
{
    // not found
}
```

Comment: No problem. You can also create the needle in one line: `std::string needle("\0x00\0x00\0x00\0xFC", 4);`. Saves you a temporary :-)

Comment: assumes that the needle is word aligned. **EDIT:** just noticed it says a "BYTE" array and not a "BIT" array.

Comment: Your first example with std::string will make a copy of the data, which can be horrendous for large arrays.

Comment: @BrandonL: Sure, maybe, sometimes. Measure and choose. Sometimes a simple solution has value, too, even though it may not have optimal performance.

Answer (score 9):

You want something like [`memmem`](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2007-12/msg00000.html) (that code is licensed with the GPL).

However, it should not be difficult to roll your own. Like in `memmem`'s implementation, you need a loop that uses [`memchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memchr) to find the first character of your needle in the haystack, and [`memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp) to test each hit and see if all of your needle is there.

Comment: @R..: Admittedly I did not look for others, and I only linked to it as an example. In the OP's shoes I 'd take my own advice and roll my own, as it's a simple matter really.

Comment: Rolling your own is not a bad idea, but O(N²) is pretty bad, especially when O(N) with best-case approaching N/M is possible...

Comment: @R..: Much easier to implement than a Boyer-Moore equivalent though. But anyway, what I 'd like to hear is how to amend the answer to make it useful (let's limit it to plain C since the accepted answer is a good C++ approach).

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to use raw pointers with `std::search()`.

For example:

```
#include <algorithm>

BYTE Buffer[20000] = { 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFC };
PBYTE pBufferLast = Buffer + sizeof(Buffer);
BYTE Pattern[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFC };
PBYTE pPatternLast = Pattern + sizeof(Pattern);

PBYTE pOccurrence = std::search(Buffer, pBufferLast, Pattern, pPatternLast);

BOOL fFound = (pOccurrence != pBufferLast);
```

Since `C++17`, `std::search()` can use Boyer-Moore search ([boyer_moore_searcher](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_searcher)), etc.

Comment: Your tip with the STL and the searchers was amazing. I ended up implementing the Boyer-Moore-Horspool searcher and it's the fastest algorithm I've found for large haystacks: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_horspool_searcher

Answer (score 3):

Try this, just needed it:

```
// Returns a pointer to the first byte of needle inside haystack, 
static uint8_t* bytes_find(uint8_t* haystack, size_t haystackLen, uint8_t* needle, size_t needleLen) {
    if (needleLen > haystackLen) {
        return false;
    }
    uint8_t* match = memchr(haystack, needle[0], haystackLen);
    if (match != NULL) {
        size_t remaining = haystackLen - ((uint8_t*)match - haystack);
        if (needleLen <= remaining) {
            if (memcmp(match, needle, needleLen) == 0) {
                return match;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple/naive solution using C buffers:

```
const char *find_needle(const char *haystack, size_t haystack_length, const char *needle, size_t needle_length) {
    for (size_t haystack_index = 0; haystack_index < haystack_length; haystack_index++) {

        bool needle_found = true;
        for (size_t needle_index = 0; needle_index < needle_length; needle_index++) {
            const auto haystack_character = haystack[haystack_index + needle_index];
            const auto needle_character = needle[needle_index];
            if (haystack_character == needle_character) {
                continue;
            } else {
                needle_found = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (needle_found) {
            return &haystack[haystack_index];
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

A more efficient solution would be using the [`Knuth-Morris-Pratt` algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) for example but the implementation is also more complex.

**EDIT:**
Using `C++17` the fastest solution I found was using `std::search` and the [boyer_moore_horspool_searcher](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/boyer_moore_horspool_searcher).

Answer (score -3):

'Tarion' his posted function was almost perfect. But it did a 'memcmp' to much (rechecking the first char again that it already did with 'memchr'. And it didnt work if more of the first characters would be in the array followed by not always the needle bytes afterwards.
So here you see 2 posts, just copy it into your C++ project and call the function TestIt()

You can modify it to your own wishes.
Also know that a char* is just a char[] array but as a pointer. So if you see a '&' in front of a char variable its just to use the char* as a regular char[] by index by returning the pointer to that index.
Also to redim arrays that arent fixed sizes, use the 'malloc' C++ function.
And do never EVER listen to C++ programmers who point you to use C String functions to search for binary data. They suck big time.
Stick with C++ functions only.

**How to use.:**
Search Bytes Routine for C++ (PART 1/2 and PART 2/2) for your find bytes function and copy it into your C++ project, you have to copy it all (also the header lines in the white area above it, and below for PART 2/2 where you see the '}' char in white area), i couldnt upload it all to well because of StackOverflow post errors and im in a hurry.

**Search Bytes Routine for C++ (PART 1/2) - copy code here below into your C++ project**

```cpp
// Returns a int with the starting position of the bytes found

int FindBytesPosInCharPointer(char* bytSourceBuffer, size_t lngSourceBufferStartPos, size_t lngSourceBufferTotalLen, char* bytBytesToFind, size_t lngBytesToFindLen) {
    

//when calling this function bytSourceBuffer must always point to index [0]
//use the lngSourceBufferStartPos to use a starting point index

    if (lngBytesToFindLen <= 0 || lngBytesToFindLen > lngSourceBufferTotalLen - lngSourceBufferStartPos) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (lngSourceBufferStartPos < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (lngSourceBufferStartPos >= lngSourceBufferTotalLen) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (lngSourceBufferTotalLen <= 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    //memchr returns a pointer to the array
    size_t lngFoundPos = 0;
    size_t lngFirstPosFound = 0;
    size_t lngCurStartPos = 0;
    char* lngPointerPos;
    int intMustExitLoop = 0;


    //this can change underway but used only internal
    lngCurStartPos = lngSourceBufferStartPos;


    //find first byte
    lngPointerPos = NULL;
    lngPointerPos = (char*)memchr(&bytSourceBuffer[lngCurStartPos], bytBytesToFind[0], lngSourceBufferTotalLen - lngCurStartPos);

    //validate
    if (lngPointerPos == NULL) {
        //karakter niet gevonden
        lngFoundPos = -1;
        lngFirstPosFound = -1;
    }
    else {
        //current position where char has been found
        lngFoundPos = (lngPointerPos - &bytSourceBuffer[lngCurStartPos]);
        lngFirstPosFound = lngFoundPos; //we need this to skip bytes

        //zoeken
        if (lngBytesToFindLen == 1) {
            //we only want to find 1 char, so we dont need to use memcmp
            //is done now
        }
        else {
            //check if (remaining) bytBytesToFind bytes matching
            if (lngBytesToFindLen <= ((lngSourceBufferTotalLen - lngCurStartPos) - lngFoundPos)) {  //(lngSourceBufferLen - lngCurStartPos) = remaining bytes
                //memcmp = 0 is blocks zijn hetzelfde
                if (memcmp(lngPointerPos + 1, &bytBytesToFind[1], lngBytesToFindLen - 1) == 0) {
                    //BYTES MATCHING, lngFoundPos will return the result
                }
                else {
                    //MessageBox(NULL, "BLOCKS DO NOT MATCH", "Info", 0);
                    lngFoundPos = -1;
                }
            }
            else {
                //MessageBox(NULL, "NOT ENOUGH BYTES", "Info", 0);
                lngFoundPos = -1;
            }


            //validate the result, if bytes did not match we start the loop
            if (lngFoundPos == -1) {
                //new position to start searching from
                lngCurStartPos = lngFirstPosFound + 1;
                lngFirstPosFound = -1;


                //validate if startpos is still valid
                if (lngCurStartPos < 0 || (lngSourceBufferStartPos + lngCurStartPos) >= lngSourceBufferTotalLen) {
                    lngFoundPos = -1;
                }
                else {
                    if (lngBytesToFindLen > lngSourceBufferTotalLen - (lngSourceBufferStartPos + lngCurStartPos)) {
                        lngFoundPos = -1;
                    }
                    else {
                        //condition
                        intMustExitLoop = 0;

                        //start loop
                        do {
                            //validate if startpos is still valid
                            if (lngCurStartPos < 0 || (lngSourceBufferStartPos + lngCurStartPos) >= lngSourceBufferTotalLen) {
                                lngFoundPos = -1;
                                intMustExitLoop = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                            else {
                                if (lngBytesToFindLen > lngSourceBufferTotalLen - (lngSourceBufferStartPos + lngCurStartPos)) {
                                    lngFoundPos = -1;
                                    intMustExitLoop = 1;
                                    break;
                                }
                                else {
                                    //search for first byte again, memchr returns a pointer
                                    lngPointerPos = NULL;
                                    lngPointerPos = (char*)memchr(&bytSourceBuffer[lngCurStartPos], bytBytesToFind[0], lngSourceBufferTotalLen - lngCurStartPos);

                                    //afhandelen
                                    if (lngPointerPos == NULL) {
                                        //character not found
                                        lngFoundPos = -1;
                                        intMustExitLoop = 1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        //this is the current position where character has been found
                                        lngFoundPos = (lngPointerPos - &bytSourceBuffer[lngCurStartPos]);
                                        lngFirstPosFound = lngFoundPos; //we need this to skip bytes


                                        //MessageBoxA(NULL, std::to_string(lngFirstPosFound).c_str(), "Caption", 0);


                                        //check if (remaining) bytBytesToFind bytes matching
                                        if (lngBytesToFindLen <= ((lngSourceBufferTotalLen - (lngSourceBufferStartPos + lngCurStartPos)) - lngFoundPos)) {  //(lngSourceBufferLen - lngCurPos) = remaining bytes
                                            //memcmp = 0 is blocks zijn hetzelfde
                                            if (memcmp(lngPointerPos + 1, &bytBytesToFind[1], lngBytesToFindLen - 1) == 0) {
                                                //BYTES MATCHING
                                                //This is the real position in the array from starting point lngSourceBufferStartPos
                                                lngFoundPos = (lngPointerPos - &bytSourceBuffer[lngCurStartPos]) + (lngCurStartPos - lngSourceBufferStartPos);

                                                //is done now
                                                intMustExitLoop = 1;

                                                break;
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                //MessageBoxA(NULL, "BLOCKS DO NOT MATCH", "Caption", 0);
                                                //will loop again for next search
                                                lngFoundPos = -1;
                                                lngCurStartPos = lngCurStartPos + (lngFirstPosFound + 1);
                                                lngFirstPosFound = -1;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            //MessageBoxA(NULL, "NOT ENOUGH BYTES", "Caption", 0);
                                            //is meteen klaar dan
                                            lngFoundPos = -1;
                                            lngFirstPosFound = -1;
                                            intMustExitLoop = 1;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        } while (intMustExitLoop == 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //-1 is nothing found
    return lngFoundPos;
}
```

**Search Bytes Routine for C++ (PART 2/2) - copy code here below into your C++ project**
(put these lines below in a TestIt function, or whatever you prefer). And then call the function. I had problems with adding function name to StackOverflow, but the first line should have been "int TestIt(){" and the last 2 lines should have been "return 1;" and "}"

```
//test
char* bytTest;
bytTest = (char*)malloc(10);
bytTest[0] = 0;
bytTest[1] = 0;
bytTest[2] = 70;
bytTest[3] = 70;
bytTest[4] = 65;    //A
bytTest[5] = 66;    //B
bytTest[6] = 1;
bytTest[7] = 70;
bytTest[8] = 68;
bytTest[9] = 69;
//bytTest[10] = 0;

//bytes to find 
char bytFindBytes[3];
bytFindBytes[0] = 70;
bytFindBytes[1] = 68;
bytFindBytes[2] = 69;

int lngFindPos = 0;
lngFindPos = FindBytesPosInCharPointer(&bytTest[0], 0, 10, &bytFindBytes[0], sizeof bytFindBytes);

MessageBoxA(NULL, std::to_string(lngFindPos).c_str(), "Caption", 0);
```

//i know i can just pass bytTest and bytFindBytes without the '&' and [0] to the function, but it is to show you how to use pointers, using bytTest[0] only would pass the value of the first byte in the array to the function (which would give a compile error anyway), where adding '&' passes the pointer of the first byte in the array to the function. Just to make this clear for you.

Comment: It's unclear why you posted three answers. Please [edit] this answer with any information you want to share.

Comment: I've combined your answers.  You may wish to edit the resulting answer further.

Comment: thx Ryan, you saved me with this one, much easier to read now.