# How to find the sequence in the binary file using WinAPI/Win32?

Tags: c, file, winapi, win32-process

I want to identify the specified sequence in the binary file like 0001. The file opens and reads. 
Furthermore, the size of file shows well. Unfortunately, I can't make the algorythm of detecting the stated sequence. I got stuck in this trouble. Does anyone have any ideas?
The parameters such as the file name and the process name are provided by the command prompt. 
The code is listed below.

```
 int blockchain(wchar_t *box)
 {
     int i=0;
     DWORD dwCounter=0;
     BYTE buffer[BUFFERSIZE]={0};
     HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(box, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,
         OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

     if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile) {
         wprintf(L"Error! Wrong file name!\n");
         return -5;
     }

     if(FALSE==ReadFile(hFile, &buffer, BUFFERSIZE, &dwCounter, NULL)) {
         wprintf(L"Terminal failure: Unable to read from file.\n");
         CloseHandle(hFile);
         return -5;
     } else {
         for(i;i<dwCounter;i++) {
             if(wcscmp(buffer,L"0001") == 0)
                 wprintf(L"The data is found");
         }
         wprintf(L"\nData read from %s (%d bytes): \n", box, dwCounter);    
     }
     CloseHandle(hFile);
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://pp.userapi.com/c849236/v849236424/46ac8/yy8w6ak1Ddc.jpg I assume that you want to find given sequence of bytes.

So it looks that standard function `strstr` wouldn't work because it couldn't handle NUL bytes (equal 0).

Start with matching function (you can inline it in next function, I give it separately for clarity):

```
bool MatchBytes( const BYTE* a, const BYTE* b, int num_bytes )
{
    return memcmp( a, b, num_bytes ) == 0;
}
```

Write function to find sequence:

```
int FindBytesIndex(
       const BYTE* find_in,
       int num_bytes_in_find_in,
       const BYTE* to_find,
       int num_bytes_to_find )
{
    int pos;
    for ( pos = 0 ; pos <= num_bytes_in_find_in - num_bytes_to_find ; ++pos )
        if ( MatchBytes( find_in + pos, to_find, num_bytes_to_find ) )
            return pos;
    return -1;
}
```

Or:

```
const BYTE* FindBytesPtr(
       const BYTE* find_in,
       int num_bytes_in_find_in,
       const BYTE* to_find,
       int num_bytes_to_find )
{
    const BYTE* end = find_in + num_bytes_in_find_in - num_bytes_to_find;
    for ( ; find_in < end ; ++find_in )
        if ( MatchBytes( find_in, to_find, num_bytes_to_find ) )
            return find_in;
    return NULL;
}
```

Usage:

```
BYTE bytes[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
int num_bytes = 4;
int index = FindBytesIndex( buffer, dwCounter, bytes, num_bytes );
if ( index >= 0 )
    printf( "Found at index %d\n", index );
else
    printf( "Not found\n" );
```

If you want all occurrences:

```
BYTE bytes[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
int num_bytes = 4;
int index = 0;
int count = 0;
/* There is assigment in loop condition. Found index is assigned to "index" variable */
/* then it is checked if >= 0 */
while ( ( index = FindBytesIndex(buffer + index, dwCounter - index, bytes, num_bytes) ) >= 0 )
{
    printf( "Found at index %d\n", index );
    ++count;
}

if ( count > 0 )
    printf( "Found %d occurrences\n", count );
else
    printf( "Not found\n" );
```

Algorithm used by you and shown above is known as "naive pattern searching". If it is too slow, you can google faster algorithms "Boyer-Moore", "Rabin-Karp", "KMP" ("Knuth-Morris-Pratt").

Answer (score 2):

*(Answering only as I don't have the rep to comment yet.)*

Your `memcmp` usage in the comment above doesn't quite look right to me, nor the usage of `wcscmp` in the original question; you're incrementing `i` after each test, but using the same buffer pointer unmodified each time -- by my reading, in both cases you're testing exactly the same bytes on each pass (the very start of `buffer`) rather than progressing through the data you loaded. Additionally, for the `memcmp` case, you're using a `wchar_t` string literal (`L"0001"`); this will be 8 bytes long in memory rather than the 4 in your comment's call, so the comparison would be for the first two zeroes only.

The correct approach here is going to depend on the nature of the data you're dealing with. Are you trying to find the character sequence `0001` in an ASCII-encoded file, or `0001` (as seen by a user) in a Unicode file, or a hex byte `0x1`, or some other meaning of that representation? If it's the character sequence in the ASCII file, you might be looking for something like `if (memcmp(buffer + i, "0001", std::min((dwCounter - i), 4) == 0)` to check byte-by-byte for the character sequence, traversing through the buffer and comparing no more bytes than remain in the buffer each iteration.

However, I would advise against using such a line if there's a reasonable, viable alternative. It sounds like what you're trying to do could also be covered by the question [How to search in a BYTE array for a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319391/how-to-search-in-a-byte-array-for-a-pattern) I suspect the answers to that question could also perform better than such a byte-by-byte approach. Alternatively, you could consider using a regular expression implementation, if available and you're working with character/text data where the target value is reasonable to express via a regular expression.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add std in C language. If you know how to do it, please provide me this information.  
if (memcmp(buffer + i, "asd", min((dwCounter - i), 4) == 0)) wprintf(L"The data is found"); 
It shows that this data exists despite of its wrong value

Comment: Sorry, that was a C++-ism seeping in.